# Neo4j Optimizing query to get all distinct tags

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've a list of Questions and tags in my database with the following relationship.

```
(q:Question)->[:HAS_TAG]-> (t:Tag)
```

I'm running a query to get all tags which are present on some questions.

```
MATCH (q:Question),(t:Tag)
WHERE q.id < 2 AND (q)-[:HAS_TAG]->(t)
return DISTINCT(t.name)
```

When I run the profile I can see that although the results has only 5 tags, it is scanning all the Tags. Is there a way to optimize this?

I'm new to Graph databases so couldn't figure out a way to optimize this. I'm already having an index on `Tag.name` and `Question.id`.

[image: profile results]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. [ask] Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a `MATCH` pattern with disconnected terms causes cartesian products, which should be avoided.

You should do this instead:

```
MATCH (q:Question)-[:HAS_TAG]->(t:Tag)
WHERE q.id < 2
RETURN DISTINCT t.name
```

[UPDATE]

Also, to optimize the lookup of the desired `Question` nodes, you can create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) on `:Question(id)`. That should avoid having to scan through *all* `Question` nodes.

Comment: This resolves the issue. However, I had one more question. Is there a way to model this, so that even if the result has 1000 questions, I could get all distinct tags without looping thorough all the questions. I was able to do the same in elasticsearch by putting `tags` as a list in the Questions object and doing an aggregation query. I wanted something similar to that.